# command console doesn't reset after program finished running

Tags: c, cmd, console-application

i'm running the following code in c (through the cmd console) :

```
void main(int argc , char* argv[])
{

        if (STRINGS_ARE_EQUAL(argv[1],"server")){

            printf("\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tSERVER\n\n\n");
            MainServer(atoi(argv[3]),argv[2]);
        }
        else if (STRINGS_ARE_EQUAL(argv[1],"client")){
            printf("\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tClient\n\n\n");
            MainClient(atoi(argv[3]),argv[2],argv[4]);}
        else{
            printf("Invalid working state,exiting\n");
            exit(1);
        }
}
```

when the MainServer function is called and finished running the command console reset - you can enter another command line and start another program.
when the MainClient function is called and finished running, the command console get "stuck" (see picture):
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPVSc.jpg)

You can't even type.

when running through visual studio it works fine, the function return to main the main return and the console closes.

I even tried using `exit(1)`function at the end of Main, but again it works in visual studio but when running from the developer command line the console is stuck.

Comment: Try to add `printf("\nExited from MainClient.\n\n");` right after call to `MainClient` to become sure that there are no freezing inside `MainClient`. It seems that the problem is inside `MainClient`, so please make this check.

Comment: I did the check.
it printed the line and got suck

Comment: Ok, let's check that a command console works after your program. Please create run.bat file with these two lines: 1) `yourprogram.exe client other parameters`, 2) `echo FINISH`. Do you see "FINISH" after finishing of this run.but file?

Comment: No,
when i tried it with the client it got suck, then tried it with the server and i saw "FINISH"

Comment: Great. This is useful information, so I'd recommend you to add results of these experiment in the question. The problem is somewhere inside `MainClient`. I expect there is something wrong with memory management.

Comment: A new important discovery:
It's not that the MainServer ends properly and the MainClient does not, the window that finishes first that ends properly and the other don't.
maybe it has got something to do with the fact that i run the same EXE file with different parameters from different windows?

Comment: Is there any thread or other process you started in the `Mainclient` and forgot to close?

Comment: no, i'm waiting for all threads to finish and close. and like i said, if MainCleint finishes before MainServer, it does enable to write again on the command prompt which leads me to think that it has got nothing to do with the code itself...

Comment: Could it be that when `MainServer` closes first, the connection gets closed abruptly at `MainClient`'s side and therefore one of `MainClient`'s threads can't close? Probably some socket error that isn't handled correctly.